# Use enum inside property to increase vote counter in a C# program

Tags: c#

This is my requirement,

I have to design a class called Post. This class model a StackOverflow post. It should have properties
for title, description and the date/time it was created. We should be able to up-vote or down-vote
a post. We should also be able to see the current vote value. In the main method, create a post,
up-vote and down-vote it a few times and then display the current vote value.
In this exercise, you will learn that a StackOverflow post should provide methods for up-voting
and down-voting.You should not give the ability to set the Vote property from the outside,
because otherwise, you may accidentally change the votes of a class to 0 or to a random
number. And this is how we create bugs in our programs. The class should always protect its
state and hide its implementation detail.

How I approached so far,

```
public class Post
    {
        private int _vote;
        private string _title;
        private string _description;
        private DateTime _cratedDate;
        private Vote _voteType;
        public Post(string title,string description,DateTime createdDate)
        {
            _vote = 0;
            _title = title;
            _description = description;
            _cratedDate = createdDate;
        }

        public enum Vote
        {
            Upvote=1,
            DownVote=-1
        }

        public Vote CurrentVote
        {
            set
            {
                // I want something like this..
                //if _voteType is upVote then ++_vote else -- _vote
                _voteType = value;
            }
        }

        public int ShowCurrentVote()
        {
            return _vote;
        }
    }
```

and the Main method,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Post post = new Post("POST1", "POST 1 DESCRIPTION !!!", DateTime.Now);
            // 5 upvotes..
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.Upvote;
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.Upvote;
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.Upvote;
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.Upvote;
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.Upvote;

            // 2 - downvotes
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.DownVote;
            post.CurrentVote = Post.Vote.DownVote;
            // current vote status..
            Console.WriteLine(post.ShowCurrentVote());
        }
```

now I want to design the property in such way..

```
public Vote CurrentVote
        {
            set
            {
                // I want something like this..
                //if _voteType is upVote then ++_vote else -- _vote
                _voteType = value;
            }
        }
```

But don't know how to implement this

Comment: Setting `CurrentVote` in this way means that you're overwriting the value each time, not incrementing it as you want to.

Comment: Don't define the `Vote` enum as a member of your `Post` class. Callers would be required to qualify the name which is unnecessary hassle for them, and it would preclude you from calling a method `Vote`, as mm8's answer suggests. Really, at this stage, you should avoid defining nested types, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example define a public method that sets the vote:

```
public void Vote(Vote vote)
{
    switch (vote)
    {
        case Vote.DownVote:
            _vote--;
            break;
        case Vote.Upvote:
            _vote++;
            break;
    }
}
```

...and a read-only property that returns the current count:

```
public int CurrentVote => _vote;
```